# Is there an R function to split data by month?

Tags: r, split

I have data in the following format:

```
content, date    
Hello, 2019-05-11T23:59:02+00:00     
Amazing, 2019-01-08T20:22:02+00:00  
Come on, 2018-11-15T10:52:45+00:00  
We won, 2018-08-25T16:33:23+00:00
```

This is only a sample of the data, whereas I have over 1 million rows with "dates" in between August 2018 and May 2019. I would like to split my data into 10 different data frames, with each one representing a specific month (i.e. 1 = August 2018, 2 = September 2018,...,10 = May 2019).

I tried using a dplyr group-by method and also performing a loop but did not find any success. I also tried codes from other posts but to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated. I am new to Stack Overflow so apologies if I did not adhere to any form code of conduct.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try `split(df, substr(df$date, 1, 7))`. That should give you a list of data frames, with one data frame for each month.

Comment: If it is a date use `format(df$date, "%Y%m")` instead of `substr`.

Comment: Please do share some code. It's important to see which date-time class your data are or are not in (POSIXct, POSXlt, something else?).  Also, your attempts might have been close and easily corrected. Finally, don't be afraid of the package `lubridate` with its simple functions `month()` and `year()`.

Comment: @GKi note that `substr` will work for date class, POSIXct class and character class, so I think it should cover all the bases.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks, Yes, but it will return "unexpected" results for years which have not 4 digits.

Comment: @PeterK Got it! Thanks for the feedback, I will make sure to post my own code next time :)

Comment: @AllanCameron and GKi thank you both! the substr code does in-fact split the data into 10 different lists of data frames by month. Any suggestions as to how I could then compile them as 10 different data frames rather than have them compiled under one 'large list'?

Comment: @VladimirTech31 what's wrong with keeping them in a list? Instead of having the 10 separate data frames you just use indexing. It means you can apply functions to all your data frames much more easily. What do you mean by "compile"?

Comment: @AllanCameron You are actually correct in that regard, so maybe a list would be easier. What I meant by "compile" is that instead of having all the lists under one heading (i.e. Content_by_month), would it be possible to have them as 10 different headings (i.e. Month1, Month2,..., Month10)?

Comment: @VladimirTech31 but you can do `Content_by_month[[1]], Content_by_month[[2]]` etc if you want to access the individual data frames.

Comment: @AllanCameron Ok perfect. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `Lubridate` package has functions which will meet your needs. The key here is make them `Dates` (or `POSIX`).

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(content=c('H','A'),
                 date=c('2019-05-11T23:59:02+00:00', '2019-01-08T20:22:02+00:00'))

df %<>% 
  mutate(date=ymd_hms(date)) %>% 
  mutate(monthGroup=floor_date(date, unit='month'))
```

You can either manually filter for each month using that information or put it in a loop/apply to make the computer do it.

```
df %>% 
  filter(monthGroup==ymd('2019-05-01'))
```

Another way without using `floor_date()`

```
df <- data.frame(content=c('H','A'),
                 date=c('2019-05-11T23:59:02+00:00', '2019-01-08T20:22:02+00:00'))
```

Get all April 2019 dates; that is dates the came before 01 May 2019 and after 01 April 2019.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date=ymd_hms(date)) %>% 
  filter(date<ymd('2019-05-01') &
         date>=ymd('2019-04-01'))
```